# why my UITableViewController doesn't show data from my database?

Tags: ios, database, sqlite, uitableview

I have a problem in displaying my data fetched from my database in my UITableViewController. My method is:

```
-(void)createDataFromDB
{
   self.characterData = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:20];

@try
{
    // give the database path
    NSString * path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];

    NSString * pathDB = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Characters.rdb"];
    const char * pathStr = [pathDB UTF8String];

    // open the db

    BOOL success = sqlite3_open(pathStr, &db);
    if(!success)
    {
        NSLog(@"Database cannot open \n");
    }

    // make a sql query

    const char * queryStr = "SELECT * FROM characters";

    NSLog(@"Query prepared \n");
    // declare a statement

    sqlite3_stmt * statement;

    sqlite3_prepare(db, queryStr, -1, &statement, NULL);

    if(!success)
    {
        NSLog(@"Query statement cannot prepare \n");
    }
    //run a query and iterate through the results

    while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
    {



        NSString * nameStr = [[NSString alloc ]initWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];
        NSString * typeStr = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)];
        NSString * availabilityStr = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3)];
        NSString * imageStr = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 4)];
        NSString * iconStr = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 5)];

        Character * characters =[[Character alloc] initWithName: nameStr
                                                        andType: typeStr
                                                andAvailability:availabilityStr
                                                       andImage: imageStr
                                                        andIcon:iconStr];
        [self.characterData addObject: characters];

       NSLog(@" %@", nameStr);

         //NSLog(@"%@", characters.characterType);
         //NSLog(@"%@", characters.availability);
        // NSLog(@"%@", characters.image);

    }

}
@catch (NSException *exception)
{
    NSLog(@"Database Error %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
}

@finally
{
    // close the db
    sqlite3_close(db);
}
}
```

And my method to implement my prototype cell is:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSLog(@" Cell created");


if(cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
                                  reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
}


Character * character = self.characterData [indexPath.row];
NSLog(@"%@", character.name);
cell.textLabel.text = character.name;
cell.imageView.image = character.icon;

NSLog(@"%@", character.name);

return cell;
}
```

I've tried a lot of times and i can't find the error in my code.The query is well built because it works on my MesaSQLite database, but i tried to print something on the console and it does not show anything. Please help me! Thanks

Comment: Where is your other UITable code, like the UITableDelegate methods necessary to tell the UITableView how many rows there are, etc...?  You have a lot of NSLog statements, what IS coming out on the console?

Comment: here there is my UITable code…

    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
        {

            return 1;
        }

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
    
        return [self.characterData count];
    }

I put a lot of NSLog in my code to check where is the error but nothing is displayed...

Comment: please help me because i can't understand!

Comment: Where are you calling your createDataFromDB routine?  I could be wrong, but it may be that you have a race condition going on!  Just out of curiosity, what happens when you call [<yourtableviewvariable> reloadData]; at the end of your createDataFromDB routine?

Comment: I call my createDataFromDB routine in ViewDidLoad method. I've tried to add reloadData but it's still not working…and nothing is shown on the console…it seems that everything is ok but the table is empty

Comment: guys thanks for the help! i solved my problem! the error was in the storyboard. the name didn't match with my class…sorry for the stupid question. thanks